# Power BI Report Server not supporting Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: powerbi, many-to-many, power-bi-report-server

so I have this Power BI project that I already created with the usual Power BI Desktop. Now my boss wants me to put this project under **Power BI Report Server**. So I configured P BI Report Server and everything and installed **Power Bi Desktop optimized for report server**. The problem is that when I try to import my project into the new PBI desktop it shows an error that says that **PBI Report Server don't support Many-to-Many relationships**. But this relationship is essential in my project I can't drop it. What can I do?

Thnx :)

Comment: You'll need a bridging table of distinct values to sit  between the tables, so your old tables will have a 1 to Many to the bridging table https://www.seerinteractive.com/blog/join-many-many-power-bi/

Answer (score 0):

Use the normal Power BI Desktop version, and upload the .PBIX file directly at the web portal of the Power BI server. Pay attention to the release, it must match your Power BI Server. For example, for Power BI Server january/2020, use Power BI Desktop december/2019 or below.

I think the deal with Power BI Desktop RS is that it does not support preview features. It seens to me that many to many cardinality on Power BI Server is a preview feature for now.

Please refer to:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/powerbi-docs/issues/2294

Answer (score 0):

You need to reconstruct the file or remove all many to many functionality + your model must not be composite (data source must be the same) I suggest to use a Db to overcome the second one.